# Change the blue background of chrome devtool like before

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, chromium

Chrome has recently pushed an update to the devtool, the background has become blue (previously it was gray/black), now how can I change it back to the previous one? The annoying blue background hurts my eyes and it's pretty nonsense that they have directly pushed an update on a working field, they could have asked for permission from the user weather the theme has to change or not.

Anyway, I have tried changing themes from here: chrome://settings/manageProfile which is still useless, the colors they are forcing me to use, hurt my eyes. As a human, for all, it should create issues. It emmets the blue light more, and we developer use it for a long time, enough to kill your eyes. Gray and black were fine, not produced blue like this.

Now what can I do? Relaying on Chrome was a bad idea definately. Suggest me something to fix it. I have tried "Resource Hacker", but wasn't able to change the theme. Is there anyone like me who finds it so annoying and got a fix?

[image: Devtool annoying blue background]

Comment: It's a bug in Chrome. Some of the themes fix it e.g. the 4th one works for me: https://puu.sh/K3pb2/cca5ff20c6.png

Comment: Hello, no, It's not a bug. They have done it purposefully. I'm also using that one, as a temporary solution, but still.. that color also produces blue light a lot compared to the previous one.

Comment: It's a bug, https://crbug.com/330678210.

Answer (score 6):

Go to chrome://settings/manageProfile and choose a theme color you want.

Comment: I want nothing from there, all are useless to me. I want the old theme back, all the colors available there are harmful to eyes as they produce a lot of blue lights.

Comment: This only worked partially in Brave on Mac OS. When setting the background-color to black, the dev tools are still greenish.

Comment: You can also choose a custom color, like #000.

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately, it currently seems not to be possible to directly change the background color of the devtools/device view.

Best workaround I personally found, if to pick a color theme in [chrome://settings/manageProfile](https://chrome://settings/manageProfile) that most closely resembles the old color.

For me personally, the 4th option looks like the most neutral one:
[image]

The resulting background color:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

It's been fixed. Update your chrome and it should be fine by now!